How to test multiple build configurations with Unity/Ceedling
I'm trying to test multiple build configurations with the Unity/Ceedling test framework from ThrowTheSwitch.
I have code like this:
int function (int a)
{
#ifdef MACRO_DEFINED
   return a
#else
   return -1 * a
#endif
}

And corresponding test functions:
void test_function_MacroEnabled(void)
{
   int result;
   result = function(1);
   TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(result == 1, "Result should be 1");
}
void test_function_MacroDisabled(void)
{
   int result;
   result = function(1);
   TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(result == -1, "Result should be -1");
}

But I cannot figure out how I can get Unity/Ceedling to test both cases. If I define the macro within the test file, Unity ignores it (which is of course logical). My only option (up to now) is to manually define/undefine the macro somewhere within the project (or the project.yml file) and run the first test, then flip the macro manually and run the other test. But my gutfeeling is that it should be possible to automate this. But I fail to find out how, unfortunately. Does anybody know how to approach this?
Thanks in advance
I run Unity/Ceelding/CMock from the docker image throwtheswitch/madsciencelab

I don't believe this is possible. Ceedling will build your code and mocks (with whatever settings and defines you specify in your project.yaml file), and test that. It can't automatically test what might have been built with different #defines.

Maybe you can make a different project.yaml file that tests the other paths with different #defines.

@pmacfarlane I think you are correct - I only thought there was a way to let Ceedling handle different build configurations within the same project. E.g. through individual test files - I just tried that but it seems that even by doing so Ceedling will not re-compile/rebuild the binary specifically for a test file. Somehow I have a feeling that Ceedling lacks some flexibility here

After much thought on the given answers and trying some things I (currently) settled with the following:
The function itself will remain unchanged
int function (int a)
{
#ifdef MACRO_DEFINED
    return a
#else
   return -1 * a
#endif
}

But I put the test functions in seperate files
test_module_macroEnabled.c
#ifdef MACRO_ENABLED
void test_function_success(void)
{
   int result;
   result = function(1);
   TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(result == 1, "Result should be 1");
}
#endif

test_module_macroDisabled.c
#ifndef MACRO_ENABLED
void test_function_success(void)
{
   int result;
   result = function(1);
   TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(result == -1, "Result should be -1");
}
#endif

Going this way both test files can be attached to the module and afterwards any project that implements the module and, depending on the configuration, calls the appropriate tests.
Project-wise, this works great. Only for testing the module individually I need two individual projects, which I think is not particularly great.

You should do what works for you, and thanks for writing up an answer.  To me it's surprising (i.e. bad).  Your function changes behavior meaning calling code will work when compile one way but not another.  You ship a test function that is expected to fail.

No I don't - I ship some test functions that will not be executed with a certain configuration, while others will - that is different. The functionality that is actually implemented IS tested

We agree on the facts.  In your opinion (which is the one that matters, and you have all the context which I don't) it's fine to ship one version of your function  and one that wasn't tested and ship two tests one of which will fail if it wasn't excluded by the testing framework.  In my opinion (advise) prefer to build 1 binary with both versions of your function (see last comment to my answer) and now both your tests are expected to suceed, or build 1 version and ship the matching test.
